# What is the difference between H.264 video and MPEG-4 video?

Tags: video, h.264, video-encoding, mpeg-4

Are these both the same? Is H.264 codec of MPEG-4? What if I need to convert flv to high definition H.264 video format? I want make online tv streaming and want to use PHP or Python.

Comment: http://www.reelseo.com/encoding-formats-mpeg4-vs-h264/

Comment: I suggest to ask this question in [StackOverflow for Multimedia Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/91149/multimedia-systems)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> **H.264** is a new standard for video compression which has more advanced
> compression methods than the basic **MPEG-4** compression. One of the
> advantages of H.264 is the high compression rate. It is about 1.5 to 2
> times  more efficient than MPEG-4 encoding. This high compression rate
> makes it  possible to record more information on the same hard disk.
> The image quality is also better and playback is more fluent than with
> basic  MPEG-4 compression.  The most interesting feature however is
> the lower bit-rate required for network  transmission.
> **So the 3 main advantages of H.264 over MPEG-4 compression are:**
> ‐ Small file size for longer recording time and better network transmission.
> ‐ Fluent and better video quality for real time playback
> ‐ More efficient mobile surveillance application
>
> H264 is now enshrined in MPEG4 as part 10 also known as AVC

**Refer to: http://www.velleman.eu/downloads/3/h264_vs_mpeg4_en.pdf**

Hope this helps.

Comment: h.264 is a codec. Video streams in the h.264 codec generally sit in an mpeg-4 container; often these files have the extension mp4.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/118544-convert-swf-to-h264/

Comment: thanks alphaMale your pdf is helpful.

Answer (score 22):

They are names for the same standard from two different industries with different naming methods, the guys who make & sell movies and the guys who transfer the movies over the internet. Since 2003: "MPEG 4 Part 10" = "H.264" = "AVC".
Before that the relationship was a little looser in that they are not equal but an "**MPEG 4 Part 2**" decoder can render a stream that's **"H.263"**.
The Next standard is "**MPEG H Part 2**" = "**H.265**" = "HEVC"